# Go to a previous commit, make changes and commit as new head

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit, git-reset, git-revert

It is a local only repository. No branches. Log shows

```
 HEAD->master A
 9812         B
 4578         C
```

I want to make the current working directory same as C, edit a few files, replace a few binary files (PDF) and make a new commit, say ModC. So, the new log will be:

```
 HEAD->master ModC
 7845         A
 9812         B
 4578         C
```

Seems simple. But I have struggled and have faced all kinds of branches, merges, rebases, resets!

What is the sure-shot, fool-proof way of achieving what I want to?

Comment: Resetting branch to previous commit happens only if you do not need the current commit changes (in your case revert commit `A`). But from your second scheme it seems that you want to only create a new commit with modified changes from commit `B` and keep the changes in commit `A`.

Comment: Yes. I want to achieve exactly what I have described in the question.

Comment: So do you still need commits `A` & `B` or not?

Comment: @Eimantas Yes. I do not want to lose any commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve that :

```
# get content of 'C' commit (without creating any commit yet) :
git checkout 4578 -- .  # <- the '.' is very important. see below

# edit whatever files you want ...

# make regular commit with your new content :
git add <files>
git commit
```

---

The subtle difference :

```
git checkout 4578
```

will *set the active commit to `4578`* and put the content of commit `4578` on disk

```
git checkout 4578 .
# or
git checkout 4578 -- .
```

will *not touch the current active commit* and put the content of commit `4578` on disk

Comment: The downside of this method is you've now mixed two things up in one commit: reverting A and B, and then adding new changes. This will make it more difficult to review.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to make the current working directory same as C*

You can use [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) to revert the changes that came after C.

```
git revert C..HEAD
```

This will make a new commit that reverts A and B.

```
 HEAD->master Revert A & B
 7845         A
 9812         B
 4578         C
```

Now the working directory will be the same as at C. Then you can make your changes as normal, add and commit them. Then you'll have this.

```
 HEAD->master ModC
 3847         Revert A & B
 7845         A
 9812         B
 4578         C
```

[You can read more about how to undo changes in the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things).

---

You can also make it so A and B never happened with `git reset`. `git reset` can be used to move branches to wherever you want, like moving master back to C.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard C
```

Now you'll have this.

```
HEAD->master         C
```

It's as if A and B never happened. Now you can add and commit your changes on top of C as usual.

There's an even more powerful tool called an "interactive rebase" to mess with history, but you can also really screw things up with that. [You can read more about that in the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Comment: Thanks for this. But to make sure that the solution applies to *any* previous commit, I have modified the question. Will you please look at it?

Comment: @deshmukh When you say "*I want to make the current working directory same as C*" do you mean you want to throw out A and B?

Comment: No. A and B will remain in the git. So, I can go back to A or B whenever I want. Its just that all files in the working directory will be from C.

Comment: @Schwern : you can also use `git commit --amend` when committing `ModC`

Comment: and another way is :  `git checkout 4578 . ;  # edit files ; git add files; git commit`

Comment: @LeGEC This is perfect. However, the '.' in the first command is VERY important! If you could post the comment as an answer, I would accept it